# Puppet agent disabled in Puppet master

Tags: devops, puppet, rhel, puppet-enterprise

In my environment, there is a RHEL puppet master which successfully managing over 500 nodes.
When I run puppet in master server (puppet agent -t), I am getting below error. It seems puppet agent is disabled in master. Is there any impact , if I enable puppet agent in master.

***[root@puppet-master]# puppet agent -t**

Notice: Skipping run of Puppet configuration client; administratively disabled (Reason: 'reason not specified');
Use 'puppet agent --enable' to re-enable.*

Comment: "Is there any impact , if I enable puppet agent in master" Puppet agent service normally is enabled on master nodes for server, compiler, ca, etc. You would probably want to execute it with `noop` first to view what configuration drift has occurred first to avoid breaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet should be enforcing its own configuration and the default behavior for PE is to run the agent on the master every 30 minutes.
You can test to see what would happen if you enabled Puppet using the following steps;

1. run `systemctl stop puppet` this will just stop the agent service, it won't stop the Puppet server running.
2. Run `puppet agent --enable` to re-enable Puppet runs.
3. Run `puppet agent -t --noop` if you run in noop mode it will not apply any changes, just report back what it would change.
4. At this point, if it's not going to make any further changes then you'll be safe to run `systemctl enable puppet` and start it enforcing itself again. If it is going to make some changes you don't want then run `puppet agent --disable` to ensure the agent doesn't accidentally restart after a reboot and investigate further.